# python mouse click and mousemove

Tags: python

I want to do auto mouse move and auto click, but it will be invisible, it will run in the background. It will keep clicking on a fixed location in the background game while I do other things on the computer. is it possible? will someone help me?

Comment: Background game? What do you mean by background game?

Comment: You mean you want to create a game bot? That will do stuff instead of you?

Comment: I would say, it depends on a game, particular gaps which you can crack, and create cheats(that might be illegal by the way... you better check you country's laws).... From what I see now, your question needs to be more specific.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: I'm making a bot for the game. When the bot is on, the mouse will move and click automatically, but I will continue to use the computer. ie mouse movements will be invisible

Answer (score 1):

It is actually like using two mice in parallel, it is possible as written in this [article](https://whatsabyte.com/use-two-mouses-at-once-explained/)

Also for making it you can use these videos to guide you:

[Run python script as background process](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKl7scEW90c&ab_channel=IndianPythonista)

[Python auto clicker (fixed location on screen)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4hdK9Gey76E&ab_channel=NeuralNine)

Comment: I wasn't looking for this but thanks anyway

Comment: the mouse will be moved automatically but I will continue to use the mouse

Comment: Yes, this is just for the script, the 1st mouse that will run in the background after this you can do anything you want with the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying is impossible, at least in Python. While you can create a synthetic second mouse and click a fixed location with it from Python as @Sinr Ego explained, this click will always happen in the window that is currently on top - so, you can't work in one window and have the synthetic mouse clicking in another.

What you could try however, is to write an extension for your browser - there you have the possibility of accessing any element of a website in any tab (a button, for example) and on that element, you can automatically emit a click event. For Firefox (and probably most other browsers), this would be in JavaScript, mainly.